# Repack .Net Framework 4.7 (7 Zip)

Tags: 7-zip, archiving

I've just downloaded dotNet 4.7 Offline installer from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55167) and become very surprised: single ~60Mb archive unpacks into ~1.7Gb (!!!) of data. According to 7zip info:

[image: 7Zip properties]

How is that possible? I've tried to repack it with zip, rar and 7zip - no luck, the minimal size I've got is ~600Mb. How MS did that?

Comment: Did you try to mimic the settings that are shown by 7zip for information?

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/792082/what-does-combining-compression-methods-in-7z-actually-do) give a good insight into what compression method are available in `7z` and how they are applied; although `Method: LZMA:29 BJC2` lists the compressions use, it does not detail how they are applied.